# Удобные коллекции данных

Tags: коллекции

Почти в каждом языке есть свой набор коллекций: список, вектор (или массив), словарь (или хэш-таблица, или отображение).

В каком языке/библиотеке (не обязательно стандартной) они вам показались наиболее удобными, очевидными, а код работающий с ними &mdash; читаемым? 
(Производительность &mdash; не в счёт.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стандартные коллекции в Java + [Google Collections API](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/).

Во функциональных языках достаточно удобно работать со списками, например, в Haskell.

Comment: А почему только со списками? Откуда такое ограничение? В стандартной (Haskell Platform) поставке много чего уже реализованного (про Hackage и говорить не стоит). Да и вообще, в haskell'е типы данных на сегодняшний день наиболее мощные.

Comment: Это неосторожная формулировка. Я говорил вообще о функциональных языках и о Хаскеле в частности только в качестве примера. И то только потому, что из функциональных я имел дело именно с ним.

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C
[NSMutableDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
[NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, я напишу о Python.

```
[x ** 2 for x in range(3)]
>>>[0, 1, 4]

d = {1: '1', '2': 2}
d['1'] = d[1]
d
>>>{'1': '1', 1: '1', '2': 2}

for k, v in d.iteritems():
    print k, v
>>>1 1
>>>1 1
>>>2 2

s = set((1,2,3))
s1 = set((3,4,5))
s - s1
>>>set([1, 2])

a = range(12)
a[:3] = 34,35,36
a
>>>[34, 35, 36, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Comment: Всё-таки читаемость наважная.. в первый момент показалось, что это просто какой-то дамп :)) Надо бы пробелов добавить

Comment: невообразимо повысил читаемость